# Why are our IIS 6 Application pools taking up ten times the memory being consumed by the CLR

Tags: entity-framework, memory, iis-6, fragmentation, large-object-heap

Our IIS 6.0 application pools take up on first load of a page 155Mb of memory. On subsequent refreshing of the same page the App pool memory consumed goes up to approx 245Mb.

Its a webforms application and uses Entity Framework and DevExpress controls.

At first I thought this was a memory leak, but on further investigation using a memory profiler found that over half the space being taken up by the app pool was free space but fragmented.

This pointed the finger towards Large Object Heap memory fragmentation as the culprit. There was indeed a long list of approx 980Kb which typically can cause fragmentation especially when the list grows and resizes leaving behind holes in memory.

So I've created a composite list, basically a list of lists, the idea being that as each list would be under 85000 bytes, it would be allocated in the normal heap which gets compacted after garbage collection (unlike the Large Object Heap, which never gets compacted)

Had expected the composite list to do the trick as read elsewhere that others have used lists of lists to ensure objects escape the Large Object Heap, however it doesn't appear to have made any real difference in this case, and the App pool memory is still around 240Mb whereas memory profilers report the dot net CLR memory at around 10Mb.

Am planning on doing a memory dump to see whats going on, but just wondered if anyone else had a view on what might be possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be willing to bet a substantial amount of money that what you are seeing is giant strings occupying blocks in the Large Object Heap - this is especially true with any sort of partial rendering scheme - which will contain the html output that is to be delivered to the browser.

I've run into this exact issue before, but the solution was painful - basically I had to go through and create a "streaming write" path instead of the standard "aggregate all the html outputs of the controls/views together" approach which is (or at least was) the default method of MVC, WebForms, etc.

Good luck! If you want to go down this route, you'd be looking at creating a set of rendering extensions that open up the `Response` stream and directly write to them as content is calculated.